# Is it possible to dynamically change baseURL in config

Tags: webdriver-io

Given a requirement, I can not store my baseURL value in wdio.conf.js.
I obtain my baseURL value from a third party library.
I tried to set baseURL when starting to execute a test by adding this in my config

```
beforeSession: function (config, capabilities, specs) {
  ...
  config.baseUrl = thirdParty.getTestURL();
},
```

However, it does not work consistently.

I still wish not to set full URL while calling browser.url() in my test.

Has anyone tried to overcome this?

Comment: What do you mean by _"it doesn't work consistently"_? I don't see a reason to stick with `baseURL` if it's not helping. Just have a short variable (e.g: `crtUrl`) and use that everywhere, keep it in the `global` scope, so you always have access to it, w/e you are.

Comment: It doesn't work consistently - When using code i provided before, wdio would open the URL i wanted in my first test. It then open the default one again.

Thank you for the proposed solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
    beforeSession: function (config, capabilities, specs) {
       config.baseUrl = "http://whateveryouwant.com"
    },
```

This code works properly. Page should have correct format - `http(s)://` at the beginning and it should work. Just `example` doesn't work.